# UITableView has more Elements than the DataSource

Tags: xamarin.ios

i have made a TableDataSource which uses my custom TableCell with two Buttons in it.

```
        List<ConductedActivitiesItem> _items = new List<ConductedActivitiesItem>();
        foreach(var item in this._logicActivities.Steps)
        {
            _items.Add(new ConductedActivitiesItem(){ Date = "12-13", Text = item.Lines[0], Checked = null });
        }

        var ds = new ConductedActivitiesDataSource(_items);
        var dg = new CSTableViewDelegate(null);

        dg.SelectionChanged += this.Steps_SelectionChanged;

        this.Pad_tbvMeasures.DataSource = null;

        this.Pad_tbvMeasures.DataSource = ds;
        this.Pad_tbvMeasures.Delegate = dg;
        this.Pad_tbvMeasures.ReloadData();
```

the List has 4 Items:
a
b
c
d

The Table View Shows:
a
b
c
d
a
b
c
d
a
b
c
d

Does anyone of you have an idea why the List shows more Items than the DataSource has?

Comment: How does your RowsInSection() get the number of rows?

Comment: In my DataSource i return the count of the list with items --> return this._list.Count

Comment: Problem solved... Thanks Jason you helped me a lot. My colleague also overrides the NumberOfSections() and returns the _items.Count. Now i removed this method and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your NumberOfSections() and RowsInSetion() methods to verify that they are returning the correct values.